# magento2 , setCurPage pagination problem

Tags: magento2, pagination

I have this code

```
$collection = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create()
                ->addFieldToSelect(['increment_id', 'global_currency_code', 'status', 'updated_at', 'total_due', 'shipping_address_id', 'total_refunded', 'total_paid'])
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => [
                    Order::STATE_CLOSED,
                    Order::STATE_COMPLETE,
                    Order::STATE_CANCELED,
                ]])
                ->addAttributeToFilter('main_table.created_at', ['from' => $result['from'], 'to' => $result['to']])
                ->setPageSize(self::COUNT_PAGE_SIZE)
                ->setCurPage($p);
            $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                ['orderItem' => 'sales_order_item'],
                "main_table.entity_id = orderItem.order_id",
                ['tax_amount', 'tax_percent']
            );
            $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                ['billingTable' => 'sales_order_address'],
                "main_table.entity_id = billingTable.parent_id AND billingTable.address_type = '{$this->addressType}'",
                ['vat_id', 'country_id', 'city', 'address_type']
            );
```

For example
This should have 10 orders,

```
Page 1 -> 5 orders shown
Page 2 -> 5 orders shown
Page 3 -> Same orders from Page 2.
```

How to make it return empty at page 3 ?

Comment: $collection->load()?

Comment: use `>setPageSize(self::COUNT_PAGE_SIZE)
                ->setCurPage($p);` after join query

Comment: it's not working for me :(

Comment: can you help me?
do you have any other ideas?